# How to obtain the module/object code of a Theano numpy program

Tags: numpy, theano, nvidia, keras, tesla

In my University we have a Cluster having Tesla GPUs. However the resource is shared by several departments and the supercomputing department requires users to provide uniquely the module/code object of the program one needs to run in the cluster. In such a situation, I searched for some information about this. The supercomputer has a queue system (which is usual in supercomputers to be shared). As I understand, the supercomputing department requires one to follow procedures like [this](http://www.cem.msu.edu/supercomputer/pbs_local.html). So, how to obtain the object code of a Keras-Theano model compiled for GPU? Just like the produced by `gcc model.c` --> `a.out` which is what i need.

Any other idea is very appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the object code, that is created at runtime, just run your python script with the queueing system.

Comment: Thank you @MatiasValdenegro although they are not too available for installing all needed packages in the cluster, I will ask to the SC department.

Comment: you can just install them with pip/anaconda/etc in your home user.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution should be pickling theano function, however this only saves optimized graph but not generated code. I'm not sure if this works for your case.

You can use command `theano-cache list` to find the directories for generated Op code, which is typically under `/home/user/.theano/`. However hand-compiling this into module may be complicated.

There's also a [PR](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/3350) for shared library generation however it's not merged yet.

Comment: Thanks @Kh40tiK Keras support seems to more complicated still. I'll try for now the option Matias Valdenegro suggested.